# Error RAID1 not unsynchronized - A DegradedArray event had been detected on md device

Tags: partitioning, raid, mdadm, mirrors

**My problem** is that I got a lot of mails about `A DegradedArray event had been detected on md device /dev/md3.`  and another mail `A DegradedArray event had been detected on md device /dev/md1.`

I don't know what to do with this, I tried to re add de `/dev/md3` and `/dev/md1`

I think the setting is wrong, when I buy this server they said that i get 2TB...
maybe 1TB and 1TB, and they will be function like RAID1 (mirror).

### Information about disks and mdadm

```
cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md1 : active raid1 sdb1[1]
      4194240 blocks [2/1] [_U]

md3 : active raid1 sdb3[0]
      970470016 blocks [2/1] [U_]

unused devices: <none>
```

---

#### /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf

```
# mdadm.conf
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default (built-in), scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) and all
# containers for MD superblocks. alternatively, specify devices to scan, using
# wildcards if desired.
#DEVICE partitions containers

# auto-create devices with Debian standard permissions
CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# definitions of existing MD arrays

ARRAY /dev/md1 level=raid1 num-devices=2 devices=/dev/sda1,/dev/sdb1
ARRAY /dev/md3 level=raid1 num-devices=2 devices=/dev/sda3,/dev/sdb3
#ARRAY /dev/md11 level=raid1 num-devices=2 devices=/dev/sdc1,/dev/sdd1
```

---

```
    mdadm --detail /dev/md1
    /dev/md1:
            Version : 0.90
      Creation Time : Tue Jun 28 21:37:54 2016
         Raid Level : raid1
         Array Size : 4194240 (4.00 GiB 4.29 GB)
      Used Dev Size : 4194240 (4.00 GiB 4.29 GB)
       Raid Devices : 2
      Total Devices : 1
    Preferred Minor : 1
        Persistence : Superblock is persistent

        Update Time : Mon Aug  8 16:39:07 2016
              State : clean, degraded
     Active Devices : 1
    Working Devices : 1
     Failed Devices : 0
      Spare Devices : 0

               UUID : 4878c265:cddfb861:1f51fb89:78ee93fe
             Events : 0.315685

        Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
           0       0        0        0      removed
           1       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1
```

---

```
mdadm --detail /dev/md3
/dev/md3:
        Version : 0.90
  Creation Time : Tue Jun 28 21:37:54 2016
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 970470016 (925.51 GiB 993.76 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 970470016 (925.51 GiB 993.76 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 1
Preferred Minor : 3
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Mon Aug  8 15:52:08 2016
          State : active, degraded
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 1
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           UUID : 3719a2fe:5de22a92:1f51fb89:78ee93fe
         Events : 0.5184968

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       19        0      active sync   /dev/sdb3
       1       0        0        1      removed
```

---

```
smartctl -a /dev/sda
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-3.13.0-88-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Barracuda 7200.14 (AF)
Device Model:     ST1000DM003-1CH162
Serial Number:    S1D9YP5D
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 06106d1e4
Firmware Version: CC46
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Aug 10 09:06:34 2016 MDT

==> WARNING: A firmware update for this drive is available,
see the following Seagate web pages:
http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/207931en
http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/223651en

SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                                        was completed without error.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      ( 114) The previous self-test completed having
                                        the read element of the test failed.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (  584) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 118) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x3085) SCT Status supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   119   100   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       222223544
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   099   097   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       126
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   075   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       39248061
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   092   092   000    Old_age   Always       -       7202
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       28
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   078   078   000    Old_age   Always       -       22
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0 0 0
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       2
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   070   066   045    Old_age   Always       -       30 (Min/Max 27/33)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       124
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   096   096   000    Old_age   Always       -       8997
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   030   040   000    Old_age   Always       -       30 (0 20 0 0 0)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       56
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       56
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       6549h+39m+53.503s
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       33965168865
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       80274757634

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 44 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
        CR = Command Register [HEX]
        FR = Features Register [HEX]
        SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
        SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
        CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
        CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
        DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
        DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
        ER = Error register [HEX]
        ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 44 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6175 hours (257 days + 7 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      01:42:34.881  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      01:42:34.875  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 ff ff ff 4f 00      01:42:34.820  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      01:42:34.819  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 ff ff ff 4f 00      01:42:34.819  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 43 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6175 hours (257 days + 7 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      01:42:34.881  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      01:42:34.875  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 ff ff ff 4f 00      01:42:34.820  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      01:42:34.819  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 ff ff ff 4f 00      01:42:34.819  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 42 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6175 hours (257 days + 7 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 80 ff ff ff 4f 00      01:42:30.074  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 ff ff ff 4f 00      01:42:30.072  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 ff ff ff 4f 00      01:42:30.044  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 ff ff ff 4f 00      01:42:30.041  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 80 ff ff ff 4f 00      01:42:30.038  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 41 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6175 hours (257 days + 7 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 80 ff ff ff 4f 00      01:42:30.074  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 ff ff ff 4f 00      01:42:30.072  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 ff ff ff 4f 00      01:42:30.044  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 ff ff ff 4f 00      01:42:30.041  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 80 ff ff ff 4f 00      01:42:30.038  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 40 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 3355 hours (139 days + 19 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 80 ff ff ff 4f 00   2d+10:10:04.077  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 80 ff ff ff 4f 00   2d+10:10:04.077  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 80 ff ff ff 4f 00   2d+10:10:04.077  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 80 ff ff ff 4f 00   2d+10:10:04.077  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 80 ff ff ff 4f 00   2d+10:10:04.077  READ FPDMA QUEUED

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       20%      7195         1621402896
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      7181         -
# 3  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       20%      7164         1621402896

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

---

```
smartctl -a /dev/sdb
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-3.13.0-88-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Barracuda 7200.14 (AF)
Device Model:     ST1000DM003-1CH162
Serial Number:    S1D9YSS6
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 06106421b
Firmware Version: CC46
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Aug 10 09:12:01 2016 MDT

==> WARNING: A firmware update for this drive is available,
see the following Seagate web pages:
http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/207931en
http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/223651en

SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                                        was completed without error.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (  575) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 112) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x3085) SCT Status supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   105   099   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       7934136
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   097   097   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       28
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   079   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       94580878
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   091   091   000    Old_age   Always       -       8063
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       28
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0 0 0
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   096   096   000    Old_age   Always       -       4
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   066   063   045    Old_age   Always       -       34 (Min/Max 32/36)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       27
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       178
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   034   040   000    Old_age   Always       -       34 (0 20 0 0 0)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       7798h+38m+47.402s
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       43645402353
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       75588641398

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      8059         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      8042         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

---

```
fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0b43aed6

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048     8390655     4194304   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2         8390656    12584959     2097152   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3        12584960  1953525167   970470104   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x4d10fd7b

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048     8390655     4194304   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb2         8390656    12584959     2097152   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdb3        12584960  1953525167   970470104   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/md3: 993.8 GB, 993761296384 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 242617504 cylinders, total 1940940032 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md3 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/md1: 4294 MB, 4294901760 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 1048560 cylinders, total 8388480 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md1 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/vg00-usr: 112.7 GB, 112742891520 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 13706 cylinders, total 220200960 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/vg00-usr doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/vg00-var: 773.1 GB, 773094113280 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 93990 cylinders, total 1509949440 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/vg00-var doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/vg00-home: 75.2 GB, 75161927680 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 9137 cylinders, total 146800640 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/vg00-home doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

---

```
cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name

   8        0  976762584 sda
   8        1    4194304 sda1
   8        2    2097152 sda2
   8        3  970470104 sda3
   8       16  976762584 sdb
   8       17    4194304 sdb1
   8       18    2097152 sdb2
   8       19  970470104 sdb3
   9        3  970470016 md3
   9        1    4194240 md1
 252        0  110100480 dm-0
 252        1  754974720 dm-1
 252        2   73400320 dm-2
```

---

I did a long test with smart tool `smartctl`

- The `/dev/sda` is damaged?
- I think I have installed all in ´/dev/sda´ disk and the other `md3   /dev/sdb` is not synchronized.
- Today i don't have problems with the server...
- I migrate to this server, and what is the best solution to this problem?